# Skyrim Very Long Load Times!

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

So I was looking forward to wasting more of my life playing this game until the load times increased dramatically and the in-game lag also increased.

The load time when the game is first loaded is around 2-3 minutes, when I die the load time is around 7 minutes and counting...I eventually get frustrated and just restart the game.

I've tried the following with no success:

- Deleted Saved games (Only 2 Saves left)
- Installed game to Hard drive
- Turned off all 3 auto saves

Comment: How old is your xbox and is your disk damaged? Your HDD may be going out or your disk drive.. Are load times like this for other large games? i.e. Fallout etc.

Comment: The only game I have tried is modern warfare 3 and that works perfectly. This only started happening last night with Skyrim. My Xbox is around 3 years old.

Comment: Do you have the latest patch via XBOX live?  Installing it to my HD drive made a world of difference for me, but there were texture problems early on.

Answer (score 2):

I notice higher lag times when I have more loot stored. I sell off all my loot and load times decrease. My load times have never exceeded about 2 mins. I'm playing on 360's HDD.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the load times have a lot to do with how far back you're loading.

I've noticed that if I save often, or have a lot of auto-saves like in a dungeon, the load-times seem to be fairly short. When I haven't saved in a long time, the load-times are almost unbearable.

Based on that, I assume that when you load the game will run through the current game-state and compare it to the game-state you're loading and changes pieces instead of just dumping one and loading the other.

Unfortunately, turning up your auto-save frequency creates some ugly lag when you do things like load your menus. Still, maybe try maxing out your auto-saves so you're saving as often as possible and see if that helps.