# Excessively long load/save times

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Skyrim Very Long Load Times!](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/46519/skyrim-very-long-load-times)

I have turned off the auto-saves due to the fact it takes about 7-10 minutes to do so. Even going through a door or fast traveling still takes forever. This is making me want to not keep playing for that reason. I cleared my cache and also  deleted all my saves exept for 2 but nothing helps. This all started when I got the update for the game back in January. Please anyone one, what do I do???

Comment: Indeed.  You have already upvoted that one, Mike.  Adding the same question again doesn't help.

Comment: do you have many other processes working at the same time??
I have the same problem when I run skyrim and skype at the same time.

Comment: No I have nothing else running. It all started after the last update.